# How can I sort a string that holds the representation of a list that follows JSON format in python

Tags: python, python-3.7

```
str1 = '["pwc","pok","Egyp", "$cur:USD", "ZAR"]'
```

I have the above string that holds the representation of a list that follows JSON format. I want to sort these values in alphabetical order and return a list. I did it in the below way:

```
def Convert(string):
    li = list(string.split(","))
    return li
  
# Driver code    
str1 = '["pwc","pok","Egyp", "$cur:USD", "ZAR"]'
print('Before sort')
print(str1)
lst = Convert(str1.strip("[]"))
print(lst)
print('After sort')
lst.sort()
print(lst)
```

The output I'm getting is `[' "$cur:USD"', ' "ZAR"', '"Egyp"', '"pok"', '"pwc"']`

But I want it in the below format(basically without the single quote(') between each values):

```
["$cur:USD","ZAR","Egyp","pok","pwc"]
```

Can anyone please help me in this.

Comment: First of all, what you have written at top, is not a list of strings. It is a complete string because of the `''`

Comment: Yes @PCM. 
As azro mentioned , it should be "a string that holds the representation of a list that follows JSON format"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To clarify you

- don't have "string which contains a list of string values"
- have "a string that holds the **representation** of a list that follows [JSON format](https://www.json.org/json-en.html)

So use `json` to load it, from string representation to python object

```
import json

str1 = '["pwc","pok","Egyp", "$cur:USD", "ZAR"]'
lst = sorted(json.loads(str1))
print(lst)  # ['$cur:USD', 'Egyp', 'ZAR', 'pok', 'pwc']
```

Comment: Yes,That's true. I am updating description. Thanks @azro

Comment: Ohk. Awesome.So I can import the json and do it. Thanks azro. I am new to Python world.  Thanks for the update. It makes it really simple.

Answer (score 1):

```
str1 = '["pwc","pok","Egyp", "$cur:USD", "ZAR"]'    
print(sorted(eval(str1)))
```

Warning: Use only if `str1` is trusted input and you're sure that `str1` is a valid python list